# problems with the lmest function in R

Tags: r, timedelta

When fitting the model for latent transition using R's LMest package, I had problems inserting covariates into the fit.
My response variables are binary and my adjustment variables are binary.
My database is in long format as the prints will show. I tried a few ways but they all return the same error message.
I will post prints that show.
Important note: The base is balanced.
I'm waiting for answers that help me.

database
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSLYf.png)

fit

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZLLk.png)

error message

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xA8P.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dqlyt.png)

I tried several ways and it returns the same error message.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please [do not post code or data in images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2372064)